# Angular: Editing a specific element in a behaviour subject of type <T[]>

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I got an html table showing a list of sequences, I'm populating this page using a BehaviourSubject of type Sequence[]

```
   private sequencesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Sequence[]>([]);

   findSequences(pageIndex: number, pageSize: number, rrc: string): Observable<PaginatedResult> {

        return this.http.get<PaginatedResult>('https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/' + rrc + '/sequence', {
            params: new HttpParams()
                .set('page', pageIndex.toString())
                .set('limit', pageSize.toString())
        });
    }

   loadSequences(pageIndex: number,
                  pageSize: number,
                  rrc: string) {

        this.loadingSubject.next(true);

        this.sequencesService.findSequences(pageIndex, pageSize, rrc).pipe(
                /*catchError(() => of([]))*/
                finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
                tap(x => this.length.next(x.total))
            )
            .subscribe((sequences: PaginatedResult) => this.sequencesSubject.next(sequences.items));
    }
```

These are the interfaces for PaginatedResult and Sequence

```
export interface PaginatedResult{
  readonly items: Sequence[];
  readonly total: number;
}
```

My table contains a sequence in each row, this rows are expandable. When the rows expand (when i click on them) they show more data referred to that specific sequence, I want this data to be populated only when the rows are clicked. I'm trying to create a method that edits my sequencesSubject replacing the sequence i clicked on with the one i get from an http request

```
getSequence(id: string): Observable<Sequence> {
      return this.http.get<Sequence>('https://bgpie.net/api/sequence/' + id);
    }
```

I don't know how to access a specific element of the sequencesSubject replacing it with the one I get from getSequence.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the most recent value from your `BehaviorSubject`, replace the sequence matching `id` with the value you retrieve from your network call, and then emit the new array.

```js
class SequencesList {
  private sequencesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Sequence[]>([]);

  constructor(private http: Http, private sequencesService: SequencesService) {
    sequencesService.findSequences().subscribe(sequences =>
      this.sequencesSubject.next(sequences);
    );
  }

  async onSequenceClick(event: any) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    const sequenceWithDetails = this.http.get<Sequence>('/api/sequence/' + id);
    const sequences = this.sequencesSubject.getValue();
    const sequenceIndex = sequences.findIndex(seq => seq.id === id);
    sequences[sequenceIndex] = sequenceWithDetails;
    this.sequencesSubject.next(sequences);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there really no way of doing that with a BehaviorSubject? My whole project is based around that.

Comment: You can emit the new `sequences` using a subject, if you'd like. Updated my answer to reflect that approach.